# dart - interfaces with properties

Tags: flutter, dart

How come in dart I can't do this?

```
abstract class IUserDto {
  String id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;
}

class UserLogicItem implements IUserDto {
  UserLogicItem({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email});
  @override
  final String id;
  @override
  final String firstName;
  @override
  final String lastName;
  @override
  final String email;
}
```

I get this error:

> Missing concrete implementations of 'setter IUserDto.email', 'setter
> IUserDto.firstName', 'setter IUserDto.id', and 'setter
> IUserDto.lastName'. Try implementing the missing methods, or make the
> class abstract.dart(non_abstract_class_inherits_abstract_member)

But I want to create a class contract where the concrete class has to have those properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UserLogicItem implements IUserDto {
  UserLogicItem({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email});

  @override
  String email;

  @override
  String firstName;

  @override
  String id;

  @override
  String lastName;
 
}
```

Comment: I couldn't think of this one. Nice. Also, please add some details in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the missing setters in the `UserLogicItem` and it'll resolve this issue. You can press `Ctrl + Enter` to quickly add the missing overrides or use `Ctrl + O` from the class to check missing overrides.

```dart
class UserLogicItem implements IUserDto {
  UserLogicItem({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email});
  @override
  final String id;
  @override
  final String firstName;
  @override
  final String lastName;
  @override
  final String email;

  @override
  void set email(String _email) {
    // TODO: implement email
  }

  @override
  void set firstName(String _firstName) {
    // TODO: implement firstName
  }

  @override
  void set id(String _id) {
    // TODO: implement id
  }

  @override
  void set lastName(String _lastName) {
    // TODO: implement lastName
  }
}
```